# How to store and show dates with VBA Calendar Object

Tags: vba, calendar

Using VBA in Excel, I'd like to select some dates (and store them) by using the Calendar Object

I created

```
Private Sub Calendar1_Click()
    StartDate = Calendar1.Value
    MsgBox (StartDate)
End Sub
```

but now I'd like to store "StartDate" to show it again on the calendar when clicking the sheet and to make some calculations.

I don't have any idea about how to do it. Any tip is welcome

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Please show an example.

Comment: Create a Public variable `StartDate` in your module and then you can store the date in it. Later to show the same date, you can use `Calendar1.Value = StartDate`

Comment: Jean-François: I'm trying to create an application to store the birthdays of my friends. I want to select the dates (they are 20) on the calendar. When a day is selected, it must be marked in red, and the application must store these dates. I've accomplished the second part (store dates) by using an auxiliar Excel sheet, but I have no idea about how to mark the days in red.

Comment: Siddharth: Does "Calendar1" object accept more than one "Value"s?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this lite useful calendar
[download](http://allenbrowne.com/binary/calendar2k.zip) there is its [documentation](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-51.html) its also open source.
I hope this help